# intermediate image in between interactive slideshow (jQuery?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

when clicking through images on my site, I'd like to have an intermediate image appear (in this case, a graphical shape). This graphical shape should appear fully on-click and then fade out, with the 2nd image fading in. When you click on that image, another graphical shape appears, fades out and so on.

I've made a litte simulation here so it's easier to understand what I mean:

[image: example]
http://ou812.bplaced.net/inbetweenfading/crossfade_with_intermediate.gif

The gif doesn't repeat so refresh to see the effect again.

I suppose jQuery is the tool of choice. Is there an existing plugin that I can use or modify?

Grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpliest way to do this is to use a slideshow jquery plugin (you can find a lot in Google with search "slideshow jquery").

After, you only have to add your intermediate picture between the other pictures

Comment: that's what I thought, but which slideshow plugin will support that funny combination of straight-to-next image (the graphic) and then a slow fade into the next image? Don't even know what to call it!

Comment: OK, here's another visualization:
http://ou812.bplaced.net/jquery/crossfade_cut_into_shape_then_fade_out_shape.gif    
Basically i want a clear cut to another image with that shape on top of that image. Then the shape should fade out.

Alternatively one could have that shape faded in; once the shape is at 100% the image underneath is exchanged; then the shape fades out again:
http://ou812.bplaced.net/jquery/crossfade_in_and_out.gif